# Foundations without axiom schema of replacement

Tags: set-theory, foundations

The axiom schema of replacement seems, to me, the least intuitive of the axioms of ZFC. Further, it seems that, at least according to the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement), most of the applications are in set theory proper. As such it doesn't seem like we'd lose much in "ordinary mathematics" if we dropped it. Further, the previous page seems to suggest that (ZFC - replacement) is "more consistent" than ZFC (i.e. ZFC implies consistency of (ZFC - replacement)), so this seems like a clear advantage. What is the states of (ZFC - replacement) as a foundational system? What would we lose in "ordinary mathematics" if we didn't have replacement?

Comment: I do not agree with your idea that removing Replacement does not harm much mathematics. For example, we cannot access ordinals greater than $\omega+\omega$ without Replacement. Moreover, Borel determinacy is known to be equivalent to Replacement over the remaining axioms of ZFC.

Comment: @HanulJeon That last sentence isn't accurate - since Borel determinacy is a statement about a particular level of the $V$-hierarchy, we can always have replacement fail "further up" without affecting it. Friedman's result is more subtle.

Comment: To the OP, it may help to demystify replacement to note that it is in fact equivalent to the more concrete principle of **transfinite recursion** - see [here](http://jdh.hamkins.org/transfinite-recursion-as-a-fundamental-principle-in-set-theory/). In a precise sense, what you get by adding transfinite recursion to $\mathsf{Z}$ or $\mathsf{ZC}$ is the ability to perform "unboundedly long" iterative constructions - consider e.g. Cantor-Bendixson derivatives or Ulm invariants.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you for correction. I should check the details of Friedman's result after sleeping.

Comment: @NoahSchweber That is a very nice demystification, I'll admit. Transfinite recursion does seem like a natural enough axiom. On the other hand, I don't really think that answers my question. I don't believe transfinite recursion is necessary for anything I'd call "ordinary mathematics". Maybe my language is too vague. I'll say I'll take "ordinary mathematics" to mean, for the sake of definiteness, "something that could conceivably apply to mathematical physics."

Comment: @KeeferRowan Well, that's why I put it as a comment instead of an answer. (Although that said I disagree with your definition of "ordinary mathematics," since things like Ulm invariants are in fact pretty standard fare within mathematics - I think something like "concrete mathematics" would be better.)

Comment: Also related: https://karagila.org/2019/in-praise-of-replacement/

Comment: @HanulJeon See my previous comment about "ordinary mathematics". I don't believe Borel determinacy would be considered "ordinary mathematics" by this definition. Of course set theory is affected by set theoretic axioms, but in more physically/concretely motivated fields, does replacement matter? If not, why is it uncontroversially used?

Comment: "in more physically/concretely motivated fields, does replacement matter? If not, why is it uncontroversially used?" Keep in mind that its status as a foundational axiom is determined by the broader mathematical community, not just its "concrete" subfields. Moreover, one of the goals of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is precisely to overshoot what we actually need, so that we don't need to worry about foundational issues in day-to-day mathematics. The search for a *minimal* acceptable foundational theory is quite different from the motivation of $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

Comment: On that note, you may be interested in **reverse mathematics**. The vast majority of concrete mathematics can already be developed in the weak theory $\mathsf{ACA_0}$. So if you want to go "conservative," you should abandon the $\mathsf{ZFC}$ framework entirely (the gap between $\mathsf{ACA_0}$ and $\mathsf{Z}$ is extremely vast).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Your post says that replacement is basically equivalent to "no matter how you code ordered pairs, the set of ordered pairs exists", but then you claim replacement is necessary for indifference between the two distinct codings of ordered pairs $A^2$ and $A \times A$. This doesn't seem right, since we can, for any $A$, just explicitly (without replacement) construct a set function $A^2 \to A \times A$ and prove it to be a bijection. Similarly, without replacement, we can be indifferent to any coding of ordered pairs for which we can prove the collection of ordered pairs is a set.

Comment: @KeeferRowan: How do you define $A\times A$? You *picked* a definition first. Then you applied an argument that says that $A^2$ is "practically the same" as $A\times A$. But you haven't told me *what* is $A\times A$. Of course you won't need replacement for this argument if you chose a simple encoding of ordered pairs (e.g. Kuratowski's).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue of two different perspectives "talking past each other."

$\mathsf{ZFC}$ is indeed massively overshooting what we actually need for "concrete" mathematics (I disagree with the use of "ordinary" mathematics in this context). But that's part of the point *(well, that's ahistorical; rather, it has emerged as part of the appeal)*. By settling on such a strong theory as $\mathsf{ZFC}$ as our "default" theory for mathematics, we save mathematicians a lot of effort: it's easy to convince oneself that a given "natural-language" proof actually translates into $\mathsf{ZFC}$ - or more accurately, that if there is a serious issue re: fully formalizing that natural-language proof, it's not related to $\mathsf{ZFC}$ but rather reflects a genuine ambiguity/gap/error in the natural-language argument itself.

The question of what foundations are actually *needed* for various parts of mathematics is however an extremely interesting one. The relevant topic is **reverse mathematics**, and broadly speaking I'd say that the theory $\mathsf{ACA_0}$ is the "right" one for most contexts. For example, despite its extreme complexity it's generally believed that the proof of Fermat's Last Theorem can be modified to go through in $\mathsf{ACA_0}$. And this is well below $\mathsf{Z}$ *(= $\mathsf{ZFC}$ without choice or replacement)* in power.

That said, there are arguably concrete results which require serious axiomatic strength - this has been most intensively studied by Harvey Friedman (e.g. with Boolean relation theory). The relevant statements are fairly innocuous-seeming combinatorial principles. Now contra Friedman I don't actually find these statements particularly natural, and I think this is a common stance, but certainly his work points towards a real possibility that we may eventually find ourselves grappling with set-theoretic principles - at least up to consistency strength - in even very concrete questions.

Comment: I accepted the answer since I think it basically clarifies things. I will note though that it seems weird that choice is considered the controversial axiom in ZFC, while it seems that replacement is less natural, less necessary, and more of jump (in terms of consistency and whatnot). I think I might have over shot with "concrete math" as the standard; choice has some nice results outside of set theory (every vector space has a basis, etc.) and though they aren't concrete, I would say they are more in the "mainstream" than stuff purely in set theory (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) This isn't a dig at set theory, it just seems like there are a lot of axioms one could choose to accept or not, and that will deeply affect what your resulting set theory is, and it seems like one should be basically ambivalent about what axioms to take. In something like linear algebra though, it comes up as a concrete field and then gets more abstract. Choice let's you take something that works in the concrete (finite dimensional) case and take it to the abstract case. It doesn't seem like replacement is doing as much, though that is probably just my lack of knowledge about set theory

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I'm not qualified to answer this question. Having said that, [this paper](http://math.bu.edu/people/aki/20.pdf) seems relevant; I especially found the following quote stimulating, although it only addresses whether replacement is "intuitive", rather than its relevance to "ordinary mathematics".

> Replacement can be seen as a crucial bulwark of indifference to
> identification, in set theory and in modern mathematics generally. To
> describe a prominent example, several definitions of the real numbers
> as generated from the rational numbers have been put forward — in terms
> of the geometric continuum, Dedekind cuts, and Cauchy sequences — yet in
> mathematical practice there is indifference to actual identification
> with any particular objectification as one proceeds to work
> with the real numbers.  In set theory, one opts for a particular
> representation for an ordered pair, for natural numbers, and so forth.
> What Replacement does is to allow for articulations that these
> representations are not necessary choices and to mediate generally
> among possible choices. Replacement is a corrective for the other
> axioms, which posit specific sets and subsets, by allowing for a fluid
> extensionalism.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, though I don't really see how that's true at all. I mean I can construct isomorphisms of the different representations of $\mathbb R$ using *set* functions (which really just relies on specification on Cartesian product, which we can get from the power set). Replacement is about *class* functions, and as such doesn't seem at all necessary or even helpful in being indifferent between isomorphic representations.